# openssl update 1.0.1f to 1.0.1g broke sendmail (SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:tlsv1 alert decode error)

Tags: sendmail, certificate, openssl

Two days ago I updated openssl 1.0.1f to 1.0.1g. Everything seemed fine. But after a while an error popped up in the sendmail log:

#### OpenSSL 1.0.1g fails

> Apr 10 10:13:45 mail sendmail[17568]: STARTTLS=client, error: connect
> failed=-1, reason=tlsv1 alert decode error, SSL_error=1, errno=0,
> retry=-1
>
> Apr 10 10:13:45 mail sendmail[17568]: STARTTLS=client:
> 17568:error:1407741A:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:tlsv1 alert
> decode error:s23_clnt.c:762:
>
> Apr 10 10:13:45 mail sendmail[17568]:
> ruleset=tls_server, arg1=SOFTWARE, relay=mail.example.com,
> reject=403 4.7.0 TLS handshake failed.

The mail has not been delivered.

#### OpenSSL 1.0.1f works

Then I downgraded to 1.0.1f and the mail has been sent with:

> Apr 10 10:17:31 mail sendmail[31809]: STARTTLS=client,
> relay=mail.example.com., version=TLSv1/SSLv3, verify=FAIL,
> cipher=DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA, bits=256/256

It seems that there is another difference between the two openssl versions than only the heartbleed bugfix.

### Version comparison

Then I tried on both OpenSSL versions:

> openssl s_client -starttls smtp -connect mail.example.com:25

#### Output of OpenSSL version 1.0.1g:

> CONNECTED(00000003)
>
> 140370040759952:error:1407741A:SSL
> routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:tlsv1 alert decode
> error:s23_clnt.c:762:
>
> ---
>
> no peer certificate available
>
> ---
>
> No client certificate CA names sent
>
> ---
>
> SSL handshake has read 131 bytes and written 552 bytes
>
> ---
>
> New, (NONE), Cipher is (NONE)
>
> Secure Renegotiation IS NOT supported
>
> Compression: NONE
>
> Expansion: NONE
>
> ---

#### Output of OpenSSL version 1.0.1f (parts):

> CONNECTED(00000003)
>
> depth=0 C = US, ST = California, L = San Bruno, O = "IronPort Systems,
> Inc.", CN = IronPort Appliance Demo Certificate
>
> verify error:num=20:unable to get local issuer certificate
>
> verify return:1
>
> depth=0 C = US, ST = California, L = San Bruno, O = "IronPort Systems,
> Inc.", CN = IronPort Appliance Demo Certificate
>
> verify error:num=21:unable to verify the first certificate
>
> verify return:1
>
> ---
>
> Certificate chain
>
> 0 s:/C=US/ST=California/L=San Bruno/O=IronPort Systems,
> Inc./CN=IronPort Appliance Demo Certificate
>
> i:/C=US/ST=California/L=San Bruno/O=IronPort Systems,
> Inc./CN=IronPort Appliance Demo Certificate
>
> ---
>
> Server certificate
>
> ---snipped---
>
> ---
>
> No client certificate CA names sent
>
> ---
>
> SSL handshake has read 1771 bytes and written 552 bytes
>
> ---
>
> New, TLSv1/SSLv3, Cipher is DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA
>
> Server public key is 1024 bit
>
> Secure Renegotiation IS supported
>
> Compression: NONE
>
> Expansion: NONE
>
> SSL-Session:
>
> ```
> Protocol  : TLSv1
>
> Cipher    : DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA
>
> ---Snipped---
> ```

#### What now?

I interpret, that the presented certificate from `mail.example.com` is one not meant for productive usage...

Is there a way how I can handle such certificates with openssl 1.0.1g? `mail.example.com` is one of several communication-partners which I have problems with.

Thanks
Teddy

Comment: Exactly how did you upgrade openssl? How was it originally installed? What sort of hardware and OS is this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Circumstances forced me to compile openssl 1.0.1g from sources and I encountered behavior identical to that reported above.  This is under Fedora 18 on a 64-bit Intel.  Like the original poster reports, most mail went out OK but one mail destination suffered the same TLS handshake failures.

The openssl change log (brief CL [here](https://www.openssl.org/news/openssl-1.0.1-notes.html), detailed CL [here](https://www.openssl.org/news/changelog.html#x21)) showed only three changes from 1.0.1f to 1.0.1g:

- a security update
- another security update
- *Add TLS padding extension workaround for broken servers.*

Speculating that third change was responsible for the problem I commented out one line in `ssl/tls1.h` that appears to control presence of this *"TLS padding"* modification, like so:

`/* #define TLSEXT_TYPE_padding 21 */`

Compiled again, put the library `.so` files in place, restarted `sendmail`, and out went the queued mail with no problems.  I hope I haven't opened up new issues as a result.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there are two solutions:

- Use SSLv3
- compile without

  ```
  /* #define TLSEXT_TYPE_padding 21 */
  ```

Reference [here](http://www.mail-archive.com/openssl-users@openssl.org/msg73475.html).

Comment: So in order to work around one broken middlebox (F5) they found out that another middlebox was broken (IronPort). Hate those broken middleboxes :(